# keyboard shortcut to quickly select contiguous loops of faces

Tags: faces, shortcut, selection-tools, select, loop

So I was watching this YouTube tutorial and there was this very quick selection of an area. The YouTuber starts from a loop of faces on the right, which I assume is ALT+click, then I hear the sound of keys on the keyboard as the selection expands by one row per keypress. What is this shortcut?

[image: reference gif]

Answer (score 0):

You can select the next face ring with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd>

Comment: That's Ctrl Numpad + by the way... :^)

Comment: Oh yes thanks I've edited

Comment: Must keep these frequent posters on their toes! :^))